# When assigning a string to a pointer does it reserve space memory

Tags: c, pointers

I have defined a function which has a pointer to char as its argument. When passing a constant string to this function's pointer, does the string reserves a dedicated space in memory or can any other object override it without using a pointer to access this specified space?

Defining my function

```
void myFunction(char *p){
   // some instructions
}
```

Passing a constant string to this function

```
myFunction("Some Text");
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Really you should write `void myFunction(const char *p){` becuase, whatever you do, **don't attempt to modify the string pointed at by p**. To do so is *undefined behaviour*.

This is because the string `"Some Text"` will be copied into read-only memory on program compilation and the pointer to that will be passed to `p`.

Comment: I have chosen to use "char *p" instead of "const char *p" because i may pass the address of an array to the pointer instead of a "string literals".

Comment: In that case it would still be fine to use `const char p` in the function prototype: `p` would be the zeroth array element.

Comment: @rullof If you are not going to modify the string, *always* make the C function parameter to be `const char*`. And this actually applies to every pointer, not just `char*`. The caller might have a pointer to const, and you don't want to prevent them from calling the function with that, unless you actually are going to modify what it points to.

Answer (score 2):

That call will pass address of a string literal to the function, and that address is fixed at compile time (or time of dynamic linking when program is started, but from the point of view of this question, it's the same). It is operating system dependent what happens, if something tries to modify the contents of that memory address. In many (most? all?) modern PC operating systems, the string literal will be in a read-only memory area, and if the application tries to modify it, there will be segmentation fault. In other (older, embedded, etc) operating systems or CPU architectures, there might not even be a way to make some memory read-only, and then the string literals could be modified, but it might still cause unexpected results (see next paragraphs). **Modifying string literals is Undefined Behaviour in C standard.**

Wether that memory is "dedicated" is matter of interpretation. If you have two string literals like `"foobar"` and `"bar"`, then compiler is allowed to make them overlap, so `"foobar"` literal points to that 'f', while `"bar"` literal points to 'b' in the same memory space. Unless you are doing some very "clever" pointer comparisons, this should make no difference because both are in read-only memory.

There are some ways where the string could get modified: It would be possible to write code running with kernel privileges, which could modify the contents of that "read only" memory while program is running. It would also be possible to alter compiler so that string literals are not in read-only memory, and then they could be modified without program crashing. And for non-runtime permanent change, it would be possible to simply edit the program binary with hex editor and change the string. But none of this are a concern when doing regular application development.

---

Generally speaking, if you are passing a pointer to function in C (or C++, where this applies to references too), always make it a pointer to const (or const reference in C++), like `const char*` in this case. The caller might have a const object, and you don't want to prevent them from calling the function with that. And if the function actually is going to modify the argument, then you want the compiler to stop the caller from passing a const object to it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, It does reserve a dedicated space in memory.
No other object can override it without using a pointer to access this specified space.

Comment: ...which you must not do in this instance as that would be UB.

Answer (score 0):

No, it doesn't allocate memory for the string, the pointer to the start of the string is pushed into the stack, if you try to modify the string, you'll segfault, you can however modify the pointer.